# Are there any plans to improve the Answer editor?

Tags: support, markdown, editor

The rumors say that you've made a lot of changes to the backend so that you can now easier implement features that has been requested for a long time...

I don't know whether this feature is one of them but are there any plans to improve the *Answer* editor so that it makes use of the *huge* monitors and resolutions nowadays?

I'd be great if it was floating next to the question (left or right - user preference) so that one don't have to open another window or constantly scroll up & down while answering? It should stick in one place like the new top-bar. It would make answering so much easier without permanently loosing focus of the question.

Comment: Possibly helpful when dealing with a lot of code that you want to post answers on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/78695/31562

Answer (score 2):

I very rarely have to scroll up after I start writing my answer. Usually, you should have read it thoroughly enough the first time to not have to read through it again. If you *have* to scroll back up again, then just scroll up. It doesn't take that long. And anyway, not a lot of people use monitors large enough for this to work.

Comment: I hate having to constantly scroll. I always have 2 tabs open in case I'm answering a long question.